# Using Comparison Operators for Hex Values

Tags: python, comparison, hex

I want to create a function that performs a certain task only when a hex value indicates an upper or lower case letter, i.e., when the hex code is between 20 and 7A. Is there a way to make a statement in python that is logically equivalent to:

```
if a >= 20 and a <= 7A: perform stuff
```

? Do I just throw a 0x in front of it and magic happens?

Comment: Is `a` an integer or is it a string like `"0x2A"`?

Comment: Don't you want `a >= 0x41`? -- `chr(0x41)` == `'A'`

Comment: In fact, even if you do `a >= 0x41 and a <= 0x7a` (or, more readably, `ord('A') <= a <= `ord('Z')`, it's still wrong, because there are 6 non-alphabetic characters in that range. Why not use `chr(a).isalpha()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

yes ... you just throw a 0x and it becomes numeric ....

or   `int("7A",16) == 0x7A`

`0x20 <= a <= 0x7A`  you can also chain comparison operators like this (which translates roughly to "is a between val1 and val2")

Comment: And, even better, you can do `ord('A') <= a <= ord('z')` instead of having to remember the ASCII values (which isn't just a trivial win, given that the OP got the ASCII value of 'A' wrong).