# Regex range of hex number with excusions

Tags: python, regex, hex, range

In a program I am writing, I need to check whether or not a certain number in hexadecimal is in a given range.

I got it all figured out, except of a single problem which I am stuck at:

lets say i receive the following range: **52-71**

I need to check if a given number is within that range, for example: **6e**

How can I write a regex expression that supports that?

Writing a regex expression that detects **50-7f** is easy since every number can be generated in it --> **[5-7][0-9a-fA-F]**.

The problem is that the ranges cannot be simplified because it must except **6e, 53, 71** but reject **51, 72**
Is there a clever way of excluding the ranges **50-51**, **72-7f** from the expression mentioned before:

**[5-7][0-9a-fA-F]**

Thank you very much, 
By the way, I am working with python.

Comment: Regex is most likely the wrong tool here, what keeps you from converting your strings into numbers and do comparisons with them?

Comment: May be try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366323/using-comparison-operators-for-hex-values

Comment: It is a part of a bigger program, this is the most efficient way, and this is the last obstacle I need to solve

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to partition the ranges of interest building an alternation from regexen that matches said partitions.

Addressing your sample range ( **[52-71]** ):

```
(5[2-9a-f]|6[0-9a-f]|7[01])
```

Use the case-insensitive matching of your regex engine. In case it is not available, add the repsective uppercase ranges to the character classes.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to convert the string (since you are using regex I assume you receive the value as a string) into an int and evaluate with the normal int operators.

Using regex for this job will only make everything more complex, since they match patterns and have no concept of value. If you insist on doing that, this should do the job (but remember, that every range you exclude is going to make it even more complex!):

```
5[2-9a-fA-F]|6[0-9a-fA-F]|7[0-1]
```

You can see it with test cases and explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/ULsNZt/1)